# Shiny dashboardSidebar change when different tabItem selected

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinydashboard

I am having a following problem:

I want a sidebar change when I switch between tabItem(s).

```
dashboardPage(
dasboardHeader(title = ""),
dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
    menuItem("1", tabName = "1"),
    menuItem("2", tabName = "2")     
             ),
#I want this to be displayed when menuItem "1" is clicked
      tabsetPanel(
            tabPanel("t1", val="t1",
                    .... some inputs),
            tabPanel("t2", val="t2",
                    .... some inputs)
                 ),
 # This to be displayed when menuItem "2" is clicked    
      selectInput("s1", label="Select"....),
      selectInput("s2", label="Select2"...)
  )
dashboardBody(
 tabItem(tabName="1", 
      .......
   ),
 tabItem(tabName="2",
      ........
   )
 )
)
```

I have the dashboardBody changing when switching between the tabs but don't know how to change the dashboardSidebar values. Tried this inside the dashboardSidebar:

```
 conditionalPanel(
             condition="tabName='1'",
          #displaying first version of DashboardSidebar
             ),
 conditionalPanel(
             condition="tabName='2'",
          #displaying second version of DashboardSidebar
             )
```

But it didn't work for me.

Any ideas?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you have to add `sidebarMenu` an ID which will be used for a Shiny input value, and it will report which tab is selected.

After that, add `uiOutput` to `dashboardSidebar` function.

`uiOutput` is going to receive, depending on a selected tab, either `tabsetPanel` or two `selectInput`s.

Finally, within `renderUI`, which you define on the server side, you just need to create conditional statements. That's the easy part.

The tricky part is that you have to wrap `selectInput`s into a list - otherwise only the second widget would be sent to the UI. Even more tricky part is that you have to specify the `ID` of `tabsetPanel` when you want to send it to the UI via `renderUI`. (That's very tricky because normally you don't have to specify its `ID`!)

---

**Full example:**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
rm(ui)
rm(server)

ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = ""),
    dashboardSidebar(

    # added ID which will be used for a Shiny input value,
    # and it will report which tab is selected.
    sidebarMenu(id = "tab", 
      menuItem("1", tabName = "1"),
      menuItem("2", tabName = "2")
    ),
    uiOutput("out1")
    ),
    dashboardBody(
      tabItem(tabName = "1"),
      tabItem(tabName = "2")
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {


  output$out1 <- renderUI({

    if (input$tab == "1") {

      dyn_ui <- tabsetPanel(id = "tabset_id", selected = "t1", 
                            tabPanel("t1", value = "t1"),
                            tabPanel("t2", value = "t2"))

    } 
    if (input$tab == "2") {

      dyn_ui <- list(selectInput("s1", label = "Select", choices = letters[1:3]),
                     selectInput("s2", label = "Select2", choices = letters[4:6]))
    }
    return(dyn_ui)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Worked it out already with sidebarMenu id as you suggest as well. Did not use renderUI but used conditionalPanels. Thank you !!

Comment: Can you paste the code? I would be interested. Just started playing with shiny